# How to flatten a list that has: primitives data types, lists and generators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, generator, primitive-types

I'm trying to flatten hundreds of thousands of lists that contains primitive data types, lists and generators. Both the lists and the generators have primitive data types, so after flatten I will have only primitive data types (floats, integers, strings and bools)

Example :

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 'ID45785', False, '', 2.85, [1, 2, 'ID85639', True, 1.8], (e for e in range(589, 591))]
```

My code:

```
flatten = []
for item in list_1:
    if isinstance(item, (str, bool, int, float)) :
        flatten.append(item)
    else:
        flatten.extend(list(item))
```

Since performance matter, I wonder if there is any better way to achieve the flatten?

Comment: well, you don't need to use `flatten.extend(list(item))` you can just do `flatten.extend(item)`, but yes, this basic approach is what you need to do.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If it has generators you would need the `list`

Comment: @Cireo no, you would, why do you believe that?? The whole *point* if generators is that they are iterable. You only even need to use `list` if you need to materialize a `list`

Comment: Ah, I didn't read it carefully - I thought he wanted the iterators elements to be kept as lists in the final result, rather than flattened

Comment: See this post (specifically Cristian's answer) for the best generic flattening solution I've come across.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists#2158532

Comment: Note that your code would not work for arbitrary nesting levels.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A faster approach is to avoid the use of global variables:

```
def to_flatten3(my_list, primitives=(bool, str, int, float)):
    flatten = []
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, primitives):
            flatten.append(item)
        else:
            flatten.extend(item)
    return flatten
```

whose timings are:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 'ID45785', False, '', 2.85, [1, 2, 'ID85639', True, 1.8], (e for e in range(589, 591))]

%timeit to_flatten(list_1 * 100)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 296 µs per loop
%timeit to_flatten1(list_1 * 100)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 255 µs per loop
%timeit to_flatten2(list_1 * 100)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 183 µs per loop
%timeit to_flatten3(list_1 * 100)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 168 µs per loop
```

Note that this would not flatten arbitrarily nested inputs, but only a single nesting level.

---

To flatten arbitrarily nested inputs, one could use:

```
def flatten_iter(items, primitives=(bool, int, float, str)):
    buffer = []
    iter_items = iter(items)
    while True:
        try:
            item = next(iter_items)
            if isinstance(item, primitives) or not hasattr(item, '__iter__'):
                yield item
            else:
                buffer.append(iter_items)
                iter_items = iter(item)
        except StopIteration:
            if buffer:
                iter_items = buffer.pop()
            else:
                break
```

or:

```
def flatten_recursive(
        items,
        primitives=(bool, int, float, str)):
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, primitives) or not hasattr(item, '__iter__'):
            yield item
        else:
            for subitem in flatten_recursive(item, primitives):
                yield subitem
```

which are both slower, but work correctly for deeper nesting (the result of `to_flatten3()`, like the original approach, is not flat):

```
list_2 = [list_1, [[[[1], 2], 3], 4], 5]
print(to_flatten3(list_2))
# [1, 2, 3, 'ID45785', False, '', 2.85, [1, 2, 'ID85639', True, 1.8], <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1c92dff6d0>, [[[1], 2], 3], 4, 5]
print(list(flatten_iter(list_2)))
# [1, 2, 3, 'ID45785', False, '', 2.85, 1, 2, 'ID85639', True, 1.8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(list(flatten_recursive(list_2)))
# [1, 2, 3, 'ID45785', False, '', 2.85, 1, 2, 'ID85639', True, 1.8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

(Note that the generator expression is already consumed here and hence produces no objects.)

Timewise, the iterative solution proposed here is ~3x slower, while the recursive solution is ~2x slower for the tested input, which only has one nesting level (and `to_flatten3()` would also work correctly):

```
%timeit list(flatten_iter(list_1 * 100))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 450 µs per loop
%timeit list(flatten_recursive(list_1 * 100))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 291 µs per loop
```

When the input has more nesting levels, the timings are:

```
%timeit list(flatten_iter(list_2 * 100))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 953 µs per loop
%timeit list(flatten_recursive(list_2 * 100))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 714 µs per loop
```

And the recursive solution is again faster (by approx. 30% for the tested input) than the iterative one.

While, typically, iterative methods execute faster in Python because it avoids expensive function calls, in the proposed solution, the cost of recursive function calls is offset by the `try` / `except` clause and the repeated use of `iter()`.

These timings can be slightly improved with Cython.

Answer (score 3):

hey I made this recursive function incase there are lists inside list

```py
def flatten(list_to_flatten):
    flattened_list = []
    if(type(list_to_flatten) in [str, bool, int, float]):
        return [list_to_flatten]
    else:
        for item in list_to_flatten:
            flattened_list.extend(flatten(item))
    return flattened_list
```

Answer (score 2):

after I did more tests I found that @juanpa.arrivillaga suggestion improved my code ~10% faster, also if I put the primitives types in a variable I get my code with ~20% faster:

```
def to_flatten(my_list):
    flatten = []
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, (str, bool, int, float)) :
            flatten.append(item)
        else:
            flatten.extend(list(item))

    return flatten

def to_flatten1(my_list):
    """with @juanpa.arrivillaga suggestion"""

    flatten = []
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, (bool, str, int, float)):
            flatten.append(item)
        else:
            flatten.extend(item)

    return flatten

primitives = (bool, str, int, float)    


def to_flatten2(my_list):
    flatten = []
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, primitives):
            flatten.append(item)
        else:
            flatten.extend(item)

    return flatten

%timeit to_flatten(list_1)
%timeit to_flatten1(list_1)
%timeit to_flatten2(list_1)
```

output:

```
3.5 µs ± 18.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
3.15 µs ± 35.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2.31 µs ± 12.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterable version without recursivity. Good for large lists/generator.

```
def flat(iterable):
    stack = []
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        try:
            item = next(iterable)
            if isinstance(item, primitives):
                yield item
            else:
                stack.append(iterable)
                iterable = iter(item)
        except StopIteration:
            if stack:
                iterable = stack.pop()
            else:
                break
```

Demo:

```
In [1]:     def flat(iterable): 
   ...:         primitives = (bool, str, int, float) 
   ...:         stack = [] 
   ...:         iterable = iter(iterable) 
   ...:         while True: 
   ...:             try: 
   ...:                 item = next(iterable) 
   ...:                 if isinstance(item, primitives): 
   ...:                     yield item 
   ...:                 else: 
   ...:                     stack.append(iterable) 
   ...:                     iterable = iter(item) 
   ...:             except StopIteration: 
   ...:                 if stack: 
   ...:                     iterable = stack.pop() 
   ...:                 else: 
   ...:                     break 
   ...:                                                                         

In [2]: list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 'ID45785', False, '', 2.85, [1, 2, 'ID85639', True, 1.8], (e for e in range(589, 591))]                             

In [3]: flat(list_1)                                                            
Out[3]: <generator object flat at 0x7fe02ece1ed0>

In [4]: list(flat(list_1))                                                      
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 'ID45785', False, '', 2.85, 1, 2, 'ID85639', True, 1.8, 589, 590]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @[norok2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59905215/10416716) 's code, you can do any-level flattening just by doing a recursive loop:

```py
def to_flatten(my_list, primitives=(bool, str, int, float)):
    flatten = []
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, primitives):
            flatten.append(item)
        else:
            flatten.extend(to_flatten(item))
    return flatten
```

I just did a rough test and it should be about 10 - 20% faster compared to his given examples.